# updating Reactjs PWA without closing it

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have created an app with ReactJS and now I want to make it a progressive web app. I have seen many tutorials and understood how to do it. But I feel there is one problem that, if the UI of the app is updated then the user needs to close the app(smartphone) or browser tab(desktop) in order to get it updated. This is fine for a smartphone but when opened in a desktop some users might keep the website open in a tab and will never see the updated contents. I read that this not possible because updating this way might break some UI components and hence not allowed.
Is there a way to achieve this without the user needing to close the tab and reopen it?

Comment: Trigger a Page refresh

Comment: no a Page refresh doesn't show the new content

Comment: What do you mean with content? Content can be fetch through ajax calls. Do you mean updated app code?

Comment: I mean the UI of the app, for eg  adding a button

Comment: What is "the UI" according to your definition? React is perfectly capable of altering the UI while the app is running. That is kind of the purpose of react in the first place.

Comment: You mean you change the code of the app and want to deploy that so that the user gets a new version of the app and you also want that to be happening when the user has opened the app? You probably are lacking a cache buster on the url to your js bundle.

Comment: This is when you don't observe changes.. render values from states or put some 3rd party observer library

Comment: I can observe the changes but that will only notify the user to close the tab and reopen it. But I want to achieve this in the same tab.

Comment: @trixn can you explain  what do you mean by cache buster?

Comment: It is still not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to alter the UI in reaction of e.g. a user interaction or do you want changes to the actual code of the app be immediately be reflected in the running app? The second is not possible. Hot module replacement is just a development feature, it's not suitable for production builds.

Comment: i want the second option ;(

Comment: You can't just alter the code while the app is running and have that reflected in the app. It partly works in development and is called hot module replacement. But as an app is stateful it can have weird effects on a running app or simply let it crash. So what you can do is to force refresh the tab. A cache buster is a unique key in the name of the js bundle to prevent browsers from caching an old version of the code. Every time you create a new version of the app the key will change which will intentionally break the cache of the browser.

Comment: @sandeepkumarsingh i want exactly the same things in CRA PWA typescript react app. have you find any solution for this  ?